# Where does the concept of C# Properties come from?

Tags: c#, oop, properties

Where does the concept of [C# Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) come from? And are they part of Object Oriented programming paradigm?

Some other OO languages such as Java or C++ do not have Properties. Due to [on-Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidelines of this forum, I am not asking about Pros and Cons of Properties but it's origin.

Comment: They're syntactic sugar on, e.g., the pattern in Java of having a private field `X` with public `getX()` and `setX(...)` methods. (In fact the .NET runtime doesn't even see properties, it just operates on specially-named methods generated by the compiler.) I'm not sure there's much more to it than that.

Comment: It"s just syntaxic sugar for get and set methods. That's all.

Comment: I wasn't there when c# was designed, but my guess is that it was meant to make the transition easier for engineers who were familiar with classic ASP, Visual Basic, VBA, and COM/COM+, since all of those have properties and all of them predate c#. Also plugs a specific gap because Java allows fields in interfaces while c# allows properties but not fields..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_(programming) (shows some of the languages that support it) https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/267246/how-did-oop-evolve-to-include-the-notion-of-properties would also be worth a read (since some of the answers appear to directly answer your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of a *property* in OOP is based on Bertrand Meyer's [uniform access principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_access_principle). The idea behind this principle is that directly exposing a field violates encapsulation by showing how a class is implemented.

Clients of a class should not know or care whether the data they ask for is stored in a field or computed on demand. This implementation detail is unfortunately built into languages like Java where the syntax for accessing a field differs from the syntax for accessing a method.

Languages that support properties close this encapsulation loophole by providing a uniform syntax to hide the implementation detail.